# How does context.drawImage() remember the original [0,0] canvas coordinates after context.translate() has been called?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

When I call `drawImage()` after having used `translate()`, if both of the calls are within the drawing loop then `drawImage()` will base its x,y coordinates on the original x,y coordinates of the canvas element. If however, I execute them in succession outside a loop, `drawImage()` will base its drawing location off the new [0,0] coordinate values. Why is this the case? I must be overlooking something. Thank you for any light you can shed on this!

My loop:

```
function draw() {
    setTimeout(function() {

        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
        context.translate(offsetX, offsetY);
        context.drawImage(bgImg, 0, 0);


    }, 1000 / fps);
};

draw();
```

Manual invocation:

```
document.getElementById("contextTranslate").onclick = function() { context.translate(offsetX, offsetY) };
document.getElementById("contextClear").onclick = function() { context.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height) };
document.getElementById("contextDraw").onclick = function() { context.drawImage(bgImg, 0, 0) };
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lrwbpb4/2/

Comment: `.translate` commands are cumulative. So if you translate(10,0) three times then your origin will be at canvas position [30,0]. If you want the origin reset to [0,0] after drawing, you can translate(-10,0) to undo the original translate.

Comment: Both methods work as expected for me: when you press `qwas` keys, the image moves.

Comment: Yes, but when the image is redrawn using the manual method, it does not appear at the original (0,0) coordinates, it treats (10,0) or (20,0), etc as (0,0). However, with the loop the image never treats (10,0) or (20,0) as its (0,0) position, even when redrawn. This is what is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the canvas matrices and clear the context.

You can do that by `context.save()` before the `translate(..)` and `context.restore()` after the draw to set the bring back the state of the context.

```
function draw() {
    setTimeout(function() {

        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        context.save();
        context.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
        context.translate(offsetX, offsetY);
        context.drawImage(bgImg, 0, 0);
        context.restore();

    }, 1000 / fps);
};

draw();
```

Or do it in the simple-tricky way by setting the width/height of the canvas.

So simply change this line

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
```

To

```
myCanvas.width = myCanvas.width;
```

Both ways works - check snippet below

```js
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

var bgImg = new Image();
bgImg.src = "https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png";

var fps = 60;

var offsetX = 0;
var offsetY = 0;

// Manual invocation
document.addEventListener("keydown",
  function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 81) {
      offsetX++;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 65) {
      offsetY++;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 87) {
      offsetX--;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 83) {
      offsetY--;
    }
  }, false);

var useTricky = true;

// Drawing loop
function draw() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    if (useTricky) {
      myCanvas.width = myCanvas.width;
    } else {
      context.save();
      context.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
    }
    context.translate(offsetX, offsetY);
    context.drawImage(bgImg, 0, 0);
    if (!useTricky) {
      context.restore();
    }


  }, 1000 / fps);
};

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="426px" height="240px"></canvas>

<div id="tools">

  <button type="button" id="contextTranslate">Translate</button>
  <button type="button" id="contextClear">Clear</button>
  <button type="button" id="contextDraw">Draw</button>
  Keys Q and A increase X,Y offset value, W and S decrease them.

</div>
```